# Remove the suffix of a returned filename

Tags: emacs, filenames

I set the yasnippet of elisp src as

```
#+begin_src emacs-lisp :session `(current-buffer)` :lexical t
$0
#+end_src
```

Which set the current-buffer as session name

```
#+begin_src emacs-lisp :current-file-name sicp :lexical t
(current-buffer)
#+end_src
#+RESULTS:
: #<buffer yasnippet-offprint.org>
```

A minor problem is to remove  suffix `org` from yasnippet-offprint.org.

This might be trivial, but search the elisp manual, thus did not got an immediate solution.

How could remove the suffix the yasnippet-offprint.org

The result I desire is

```
#+begin_src emacs-lisp :session yasnippet-offprint :lexical t

#+end_src
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `file-name-sans-extension`, e.g.,

```lisp
(file-name-sans-extension "yasnippet-offprint.org")
;; => "yasnippet-offprint"
```

You can use `C-h f` (`M-x describe-function`) to read its docstring. And [(info "(elisp) File Name Components")](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/File-Name-Components.html) lists functions on manipulating filenames.